# JavaFX + java 7 and Maven-2.2.1 Downloading Error

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am building my project using Apache Maven-2.2.1.

Earlier I run maven steps it download maven repository successfully. Then I was using jdk1.6.0_10, my JAVA_HOME environment variable have same entry of jdk1.6.0_10.

Now I have updated my Java version from 6 to 7, building application in JavaFX using jdk1.7.0_09, so I have set my JAVAFX_HOME pointing jdk1.7.0_09, but JAVA_HOME still points to jdk1.6.0_10. This time maven is downloading successully, giving me following error on build -

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:679)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.getFieldByName(FieldComponentComposer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.findMatchingField(FieldComponentComposer.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentComposer.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultComponentComposerManager.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupComponentManager.getComponent(PerLookupComponentManager.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:652)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 36 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29 minutes 36 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 21 13:07:49 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this an issue of Java or any changes have been done in Maven-2.2.1 version. I downloaded this version of maven and compared with old but no changes found. Can anyone sort out this issue?

I have tried to download Maven-3.0.3 (also tried Maven-2.2.1 but getting same above error) with JAVA_HOME to jdk1.7.0_09, I have clarify the usage of JAVAFX_HOME, it is not used for maven downloading. Still I am getting same issues, exception of downloading Maven-3.0.3 is -

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:679)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1897)
    at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.getFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.getFieldByName(FieldComponentComposer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.findMatchingField(FieldComponentComposer.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldComponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentComposer.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultComponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultComponentComposerManager.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.composeComponent(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.java:29)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHandler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractComponentManager.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComponentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractComponentManager.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupComponentManager.getComponent(PerLookupComponentManager.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:652)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 36 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19 minutes 30 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 21 19:13:39 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/63M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to fix those errors?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a strange setup. Why don't you set JAVA_HOME to your Java SE 7 installation as well? I also suggest to use the latest Maven version. What are you using JAVAFX_HOME for? It shouldn't be needed. The error says something about OSGi. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I have tried to download Maven-2.2.1 by setting JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09. Still I am facing same issue. I have these two environment variables JAVAFX_HOME as C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK and JREFX_HOME as C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.2 Runtime, JAVAFX_HOME and JREFX_HOME are used for other steps of building project.

Comment: @Puce I have edited my questions as I have used Maven-3.0.3 and Maven-2.2.1 with JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09.